# How to read watched films into ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am writing a Facebook native iOS app and I would like to read the movies that the logged in user has selected as "watched".

I am able to get the movies the user has liked using me/movies however am I correct in that I need to get me/video.watches to obtain the movies that the user has watched?

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to get the information. I have given my Facebook app the following permissions: user_likes, user_videos, publish_actions, user_actions.video.

Is it also possible to just get the general list of movies that Facebook has, not the one's specific to a user's profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct, `me/video.watches` is the correct call for this with the `app_id_filter=475761232465217` for the Movies app. The permission needed is   `user_actions.video`. You might want to ensure that there are actual movies listed in Facebook UI

[image: Movies Watched]

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "10101180827703747", 
      "from": {
        "name": "Philippe Harewood", 
        "id": "13608786"
      }, 
      "start_time": "2013-05-30T13:01:00+0000", 
      "end_time": "2013-05-30T13:01:00+0000", 
      "publish_time": "2013-05-30T13:01:00+0000", 
      "application": {
        "name": "Movies", 
        "id": "475761232465217"
      }, 
      "data": {
        "movie": {
          "id": "103744862998017", 
          "url": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Bourne-Identity/103744862998017", 
          "type": "video.movie", 
          "title": "The Bourne Identity"
        }
      }, 
      "type": "video.watches", 
      "no_feed_story": false, 
      "likes": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_like": true, 
        "user_likes": false
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_comment": true, 
        "comment_order": "chronological"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "id": "10101137804098397", 
      "from": {
        "name": "Philippe Harewood", 
        "id": "13608786"
      }, 
      "start_time": "2013-04-15T22:22:26+0000", 
      "end_time": "2013-04-15T22:22:26+0000", 
      "publish_time": "2013-04-15T22:22:26+0000", 
      "application": {
        "name": "Movies", 
        "id": "475761232465217"
      }, 
      "data": {
        "movie": {
          "id": "151523671552341", 
          "url": "https://www.facebook.com/CasinoRoyaleMovie", 
          "type": "video.movie", 
          "title": "Casino Royale"
        }
      }, 
      "type": "video.watches", 
      "no_feed_story": false, 
      "likes": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_like": true, 
        "user_likes": false
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_comment": true, 
        "comment_order": "chronological"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/13608786/video.watches?app_id_filter=475761232465217&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=10101137804098397"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has worked. I can filter the results using the app ID you provided. 

Is it possible to use the Facebook list of movies as a source of data or is it only possible to obtain the movies that the logged in user has watched/rated/etc.?

Comment: @user2562126 only the logged in user.